# Weird behavior when calling cuda() on different tensors in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to train a pytorch neural network on a GPU device. In order to do so, I load my inputs and network onto the default cuda enabled GPU decive. However, when I load my inputs, the model's weights do not stay cuda tensors. Here is my train function

```
def train(network: nn.Module, name: str, learning_cycles: dict, num_epochs):
    # check we have a working gpu to train on
    assert(torch.cuda.is_available())
    # load model onto gpu
    network = network.cuda()
    # load train and test data with a transform
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(),
         transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

    train_set = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, 
 download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=128, 
shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            inputs, labels = data
            # load inputs and labels onto gpu
            inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = network(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

When calling train, I get the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Interestingly, when I delete the line `inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()` I get the error `RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same`

I would very much like to train my network, and I have searched the internet to no avail. Any good ideas?

Comment: Could you please add the code of your model?

Comment: my guess is that part of the tensors in your `network` are not stored in proper pytorch [containers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers) and therefore some of them are not moved to GPU when calling `network.cuda()`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a device mismatch crops up regardless of the device the inputs are on, it's likely that some of your model's parameters are not being moved over to the GPU when you call `network = network.cuda()`. You have model parameters on both the CPU and the GPU.

Post your model code. It's likely you have a Pytorch module in an incorrect container.

Lists of modules should be in a `nn. ModuleList`. Modules in a Python list will not transfer over. Compare

```
layers1 = [nn.Linear(256, 256), nn.Linear(256, 256), nn.Linear(256, 256)]
layers2 = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(256, 256), nn.Linear(256, 256), nn.Linear(256, 256)])
```

If you called `model.cuda()` on a model with the above two lines, the layers in `layer1` would remain on the CPU, while the layers in `layer2` would be moved to the GPU.

Similarly, a list of `nn.Parameter` objects should be contained in an `nn.ParameterList` object.

There's also `nn. ModuleDict` and `nn.ParameterDict` for dictionary containers.